# Import articles via UI import feature using Zip file

Tags: knowledge, articles

I am trying to prepare a zip file to import new articles into my org/sandbox but having trouble with mapping some key rich text area fields such as `solution__c` and `Description__c`. When I add them to the csv file that I am using in the zip file. I get the following error:

> "This value [Description] in the header for column 6 cannot be mapped
>   (check both the header and its matching FLS). [MESSAGE 4/16/2013 8:34
>   PM] -- Import Failed --"

I get the same error for both fields and some other standard fields such as `publishstatus`. I checked the field level security including all the required knowledge permissions and everything looks fine to me. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My first thought when seeing the words "rich text area" and "csv" together is a possible error in encoding that data. Are all the multi-line values surrounded by quotes and any inner quotes escaped? It doesn't really line up with the reported error, but it is worth checking.

Answer (score 4):

The column headers are case sensitive. So if your field is named Description_*c, and the csv file column is named 'description*_c', it won't work.

Publishstatus is a field that cannot be imported. All the imported articles are set to draft by default.

As far as I know, all the commas and quotes get escaped automatically if you're using MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked the casesensitivity then select and copy that particular column where this error is showing or showing "This value [null] in the header for column 25 cannot be mapped (check both the header and its matching FLS)." after ctrl+C right click and do paste as values. It will work.